# Play framework: Best way to implement a fulltext search using ebean orm because of not working @Index

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean

I'm doing at the moment a project for university where I'm using the Play! framework 2.4 together with Ebean.

At the moment I'm trying to realize a live user search where a user can search for other users using a fulltext text input. A possible seach string could be "Michael Lee" or just a email address. Im passing the search string to this method where I try to access the database in a smart way:

```
public Result searchUser(String sstring) {
    String query = "WHERE MATCH (firstname,lastname,email) AGAINST ('" + sstring + "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    List<User> resultUsers = User.find
            .setQuery(query)
            .findList();

    String resultString = "";
    for (User user: resultUsers) {
      resultString += user.getFirstname() + user.getLastname() + "<br>";
    }

    return ok(resultString);
}
```

I'm trying to search in the columns `firstname`, `lastname` and `email` for the keyword but play gives me this error:

> [PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes Bind values:[] Query was: select t0.id c0, t0.firstname c1, t0.lastname c2, t0.birthday c3, t0.email c4, t0.password c5, t0.author c6, t0.points c7, t0.locked c8, t0.last_online c9, t0.date_created c10, t0.date_updated c11 from users t0 where MATCH (t0.firstname,t0.lastname,t0.email) AGAINST ('erik' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ]

Is it possible to tell ebean to create the table `users` with the required fulltext indexes? Or is there a other smart way to search in a MySQL table for a searchstring in many columns? The searchstring can consist keywords from all columns.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I tried to add an index like it is mentioned in the [ebean api doc](http://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/Index.html) but unfortunally it seems like the play ebean version does not support the columnNames keyword (and any others at all...).

```
@Index(name = "livesearch_index", columnNames = {"firstname","lastname","email"})
```

So what else can I do? Is it possible to set this index externally maybe in a second evolution file which is not generated automaticly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the play framework evolutions. Ebean is creating automatically a first evolution file called 1.sql which contains the full creation of the database schema.

For my `users` Table the UP part looks like this:

```
create table users (
id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
firstname                     varchar(45),
lastname                      varchar(45),
birthday                      datetime,
email                         varchar(60),
password                      varchar(32),
author                        tinyint(1) default 0,
points                        integer,
locked                        tinyint(1) default 0,
last_online                   datetime,
date_created                  datetime not null,
date_updated                  datetime not null,
constraint uq_users_email unique (email),
constraint pk_users primary key (id)
);
```

As you can see there is no `FULLTEXT` index created.

What I did is to create a second evolution file 2.sql. This adds a `FULLTEXT` index to the `users` table.

```
# --- !Ups
create fulltext index livesearch_index on users (firstname,lastname,email);

# --- !Downs
drop index livesearch_index on users;
```

I know it is not the best solution but it is a working one. I'm still interested how other people fix this problem or which solution do you use for a fulltext search.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is actually good. This is the proper way to handle schema evolutions.

What I normally do is to have the evolutions plugin enabled during development and then disable it when the application is ready - this way you will end up having only `1.sql` - at least until you get another change request and decide to update the schema. More info here: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions

Apart from this there is one other thing that you should consider - databases *are* bad at searching, especially when it comes down to text searches. Some months ago I was in a similar position as I had the requirement to implement such functionality (see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301843/elasticsearch-and-relational-database-combination). To spare your time reading it: I ended up using ElasticSearch for handling all my search-related functionality (full text, aggregations, etc.) and I do not regret it! I know that this can be an overkill for your university project but in a real-world scenario you **do not** want to use your database for full text search.

Comment: Maybe I do unsterstand something a bit wrong but isn't it like ebean is generating the 1.sql everytime I change something in my model? There is obviously no annotation to tell ebean to create a fulltext index. If I would write the index by myself in the 1.sql file, it possible would be overritten next time I change something in model? So I have to use here a second evolution file, right?

Comment: You could of course put the creation of the fulltext index directly into `1.sql` - just make sure you have disabled the automatic creation of evolution files. Then later if you have a model change you would need to create `2.sql`.